# DrawableCompat setTint not working

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-drawable

I am using `DrawableCompat` and `setTint` to change the color of one of my `Drawable`s and setting its color to white.

I'm using this code in my `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
Drawable mDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp);
mDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mDrawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(mDrawable, Color.RED);
menu.findItem(R.id.item_addnew).setIcon(mDrawable);
```

but the `Drawable` remains black. Am I using the `DrawableCompat` in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some mysterious reason, setting the black icon as default in the XML of my `Menu` and using `Menu.getIcon()` to retrieve the `Drawable` did the trick:

```
Drawable mDrawable = menu.findItem(R.id.item_addnew).getIcon();
mDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mDrawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(mDrawable, Color.WHITE);
menu.findItem(R.id.item_addnew).setIcon(mDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try changing

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(mDrawable, R.color.white);
```

To

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(mDrawable,  getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Comment: It doesn't work, even if I use `Color.RED` as in Chris Banes' tutorial. https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/